# rmarkdown: define text boxes and alignment of text in boxes

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown

I am using R and rmarkdown to print formal letters.

I would like to format the sender and receiver addresses as in the image below

[image]

However in rmarkdown I have only managed to do the following

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

\
This is where the reciepient goes  \hfill This is where the sender goes \
Address 1 \hfill Person \
Address 2 \hfill Department \
Address 3 \hfill Address 1 \
Address 3 \hfill Address 2 \
\
\raggedleft Address 3 \
Address 4 \
Address 5 \
Address 6 \
Telephone \
Fax \
Email \
````

Which leads to

[image]

However this is not why I need. I would like both boxes to have left alignment. Clearly /hfill is not the right use. How can I achieve defining these 2 boxes, their position, the text inside them and the alignment of the text?

I am knitting to PDF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this solution:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```       
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l}
This is where the reciepient goes \\ 
Address 1 \\
Address 2 \\
Address 3 \\
Address 3 \\
\end{tabular}
\hfill
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l}
This is where the sender goes \\  
Person \\
Department \\ 
Address 1 \\ 
Address 2 \\  
Address 3 \\  
Address 4 \\  
Address 5 \\  
Address 6 \\ 
Telephone \\  
Fax \\  
Email \\
\end{tabular}
````

[image]

Comment: will this draw the boxe lines? Is there a way to avoid the box lines?

Comment: @ECII Remove ```\fbox{}``` I thought, that you need this border. If I helped to you - you can accept my answer ;)

Comment: Perfect. Thank you very much